# get a certain part of a string

Tags: php, string, substring, trim

I have strings having the below format:

```
the_part_i_need.abc.xyz.def.uvw
```

Neither the part I need nor the rest have no fixed lenght. So somehow I have to find the first `.` and count the string I don't need and then remove it.

```
substr("the_part_i_need.abc.xyz.def.uvw", -?);
```

How should I find the first dot and count the number of chars from that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the part and not the position you could do it with the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$string = 'the_part_i_need.abc.xyz.def.uvw';
$parts = explode('.', $string);
echo $parts[0];
```

Comment: I don't care about the position. This is perfect for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'the_part_i_need.abc.xyz.def.uvw';

$pos = strpos($string, '.');

echo substr($string, 0, (strlen($string) - $pos) -1);
```

Comment: I edited it and added "-1" so now should work fine. just tested it.

Comment: Weird. Tested it on two different servers, both returned the string without .

Comment: Anyway thank you for your help, really appreciate it. Solved by explode as advised by Wezy.

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
   $pos = strpos($string, '.');

  echo $v1=substr($string, $pos); /*Output : .abc.xyz.def.uvw */

  echo $count=strlen($v1); /* Output : 16  */
 ?>
```